# Installing Rebar on OpenBSD

Tags: unix, openbsd, erlang

I'm working on an assignment in which we need to configure OpenSourceRouting's [IS-IS](https://git-us.netdef.org/projects/OSR/repos/isis/browse) on OpenBSD (`uname -r: 6.5`). It requires:

1. Erlang
2. Rebar
3. Relx
4. Procket (modified version)

Now, I've installed erlang using `pkg_add erlang`. Then I've downloaded Rebar from [here](https://github.com/rebar/rebar). After download, I ran `./bootstrap`, when I do, it gives

`env: escript: no such file or directory`.

What I've done so far:

1. Reinstalled Erlang and its different versions.
2. Updated $Path

What should I do? Thanks in advance. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was resolve by changing the first line of `bootstrap` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env escript
```

to

```
#!/usr/bin/env escript17 %I'm using Erlang 17
```

So, change `escript` to whatever the Erlang version you are using.

Thanks everyone!